# I am trying to find 1 selected rows at once after click on next button then it's to next row

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch records from my *table*, but it shows all the records at once.
I want a single row data to be viewed. After clicking on *next button*, it jumps to the next row. How can we achieve this?

```
<?php include("conect.php"); ?>

<?php
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['u_name'==''])
{
    echo "log in failed";
    echo '<script> window.locaion="index.php";</script>';
}?>  

 <?php

 $query=mysql_query("select * from  question_paper   ");

 $i=1;

while($res= mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$id=$row['main_id'];
$question=$res['question'];
$optionA=$res['option1'];
$optionB=$res['option2'];
$optionC=$res['option3'];
$optionD=$res['option4'];   

?> 

 <html>
 <head><title>exam</title></head>
 <body>
 <form name="student_form" action="" method="post">

  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


                    <tr>
                      <td height="36" colspan="2" bgcolor="#85A157"> (<?php echo $i;?>)<?php echo $question;?> </td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td  colspan="2"><table width="100%" height="64" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#A6BF79">
                        <tr>
                          <td height="32" width="50%"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $optionA;?>" id="optionA" />
                          <?php echo $optionA;?></td>
                          <td width="50%"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $optionC;?>" id="optionC" />
                              <?php echo $optionC;?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="32" width="50%"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $optionB;?>" id="optionB" />
                              <?php echo $optionB;?></td>
                          <td width="50%"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $optionD;?>" id="optionD" />
                              <?php echo $optionD;?></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
          </tr>

                  </table>
                    <?php
$i=$i+1;                           
}
?>


    <?php

$records = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($records!=0)
{
?>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  <?php
}  

?>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use pagination and with select query use limit and for pagination 
see the following link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

$sql="SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `tbl_name` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT $no_of_question_you_want to select";

Comment: sir its works but i m trying to show diffrent records for diffent log in peole

Comment: user random query to select random record from the table one of that i send u